# Creating instance of function in AutoHotKey

Tags: scripting, autohotkey

I'm trying to create a small GUI where user can create his own hotkey

I've decided to only use alt(^) as hotkey to make it simple

The issue here is the function is overriding each time i click on create in tab one.

I'm a beginner so please help me out!

Below is the code:

```
#SingleInstance, force

; Layout
;--------

Gui, Font, s12
Gui, Add, Text, x70 y20, Available Shortcuts
Gui, Font, s11
Gui, Add, Button, x280 y60 w100 gAdd_Shortcut, Add
Gui, Add, Button, x280 y130 w100 gDelete_Shortcut, Delete
Gui, Add, Button, x280 y200 w100 gClose_App, Close
Gui, 1:Color, C8C8C8
Gui, 1:Show, w450 h300, Shortcut Builder 
List:="a||b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|m|n|o|p|q|r|s|t|u|v|"
return


;Lables
;-------

Add_Shortcut:
Gui, 2:Destroy
Gui, 2:Font, s11
Gui, 2:Color, C8C8C8
Gui, 2:Add, Tab3, x0 y0 w350 h220 Border,Add Key|Add Text|
Gui, 2:Tab, 1
Gui, 2:Add, Text, x10 y40, Enter a text in the below field
Gui, 2:Add, Text, x245 y40, Select Key
Gui, 2:Add, Edit, x10 y70 w200 h100 vEdit1 gSubmit_edit1
Gui, 2:Add, DropDownList, x230 y70 w100 vDDL gSubmit_All, % List
Gui, 2:Add, Button, x240 y130 w80 gCreate_Key, Create
Gui, 2:Tab, 2
Gui, 2:Add, Text, x10 y40, Enter a text in the below field
Gui, 2:Add, Text, x200 y40,`       Enter short text
Gui, 2:Add, Edit, x10 y70 w170 h100 vEdit2
Gui, 2:Add, Edit, x200 y70 w140 h50 vEdit3
Gui, 2:Add, Button, x230 y140 w80, Create

Gui, 2:Show, w350 h220, Add Shortcuts
return
```

This is where the function is overriding each time

```
Create_key:
    key:= "!"+DDL
    Hotkey, %key%, myKey
    return
    myKey:
        Send, % Edit1
        return

Submit_edit1:
    Gui, Submit, NoHide
    return

Submit_All:
    Gui, Submit, NoHide
    return

Delete_Shortcut:
    return

Close_App:
    ExitApp
    return

GuiClose:
    ExitApp
```

I need find a  way to make the function store all the previously created keys even after i close and open the application again.
Note: Ignore the second tab i'm still working on it!

Comment: If you want to keep the keys even after restarting the application, then you need to store them somewhere. An [ini file](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/IniWrite.htm) would be an easy way, or a simple database (like sqlite).

Comment: Okay I'll look into it, one more question, Each time i enter a text, select a key and click on create, all the previously created texts for the keys are being overridden by the current text. Is the logic in my code incorrect?